# Is there anyway to use templates NOT as parameters, but as a global type?

Tags: c++, templates

Whenever I create a template I know to pass it in as function arguments, but is there any particular reason why I cannot use templates inside of my main function?

```
template <class Tmp>

int main()
{
   Tmp pizza;

}
```

But passing as parameter will always work

```
template <class Tmp>
Tmp add(Tmp x, Tmp y)
{
    return x+y;

}
```

The above code will not run and next to my attempted variable declaration line it state "Unknown type 'Tmp' ", but I assumed that because I declared template  outside of my main function it would take this into account. Is there any particular reason why this is so? It seems as if everyone just uses templates inside function parameters and nothing more.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `typedef`?

Comment: With the syntax is the first snippet, how (and when) would you expect the template to be instanciated ? What would `Tmp` be ?

Comment: What tells `pizza` what type it is?

Comment: We use them also for classes.

Comment: I think using `main()` is a bad example because you don't get to call `main()` so you have no way of supplying the template parameter. Maybe try using a different function?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with your first snippet?  What "should" happen?

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there. But C++ is a *statically-typed* language, so the compiler needs to know the *type* for `pizza` at *compile-time*. This

```
template <class Y> struct/*members are public by default*/ Tmp
{
    typedef Y type;
};

int main()
{
    Tmp<int>::type pizza; /*pizza will be an int*/
}
```

is legal.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are not code. Templates are ... well they are templates. Before you can call a template function it has to be instantiated. E.g.

```
template <class T> T foo(T x) { return T;}
```

This is just a template, ie if you write this alone the compiler will not create a single line of code for this. Only when you instantiate and use it the compiler will do something:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = foo<int>(x);  // compiler instantiates the template and calls the int instance
}
```

In your first snippet the compiler does not know what type it should use to instantiate the template. Moreover, you cannot make `main` a template, because the entry point of any program has to be `int main()`.

PS:

> It seems as if everyone just uses templates inside function parameters and nothing more.

There are more things that one can do with templates. I like to think about templates as **the way** to parametrize my code whenever the parameter can be choosen at compile time. Consider this (a bit contrived) example:

```
// template taking a functor as argument
// (more precisely: a default constructible callable type)
template <typename op,typename T> void plug(T x) {
   std::cout << "op(" << x << ") = " << op()(x) << "\n";
}

// a simple functor
template <typename T>
struct identity { T operator()(T x){return x;} };   

int main() {
    plug<identity<double>,double>(2.0);
}
// prints: 
// op(2) = 2
```

Once instantiated, the parameter does not appear as function parameter, but it rather controls what the (templated) function is actually doing with its parameter.

Comment: "Templates are not code. Templates are ... well they are templates". Well put, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any particular reason why I cannot use templates inside of my main function

There's no reason you can't, but your code *does not use templates inside your main function*. Rather, your code is trying to define `main` to be a function template. This is no good, because the signature of `main` is specified in the standard and it's not a function template. Granted, implementations are permitted to specify alternatives, but this doesn't help you because your implementation doesn't specify any template function alternatives. My compiler (gcc) gives a more forthright error message than yours, it says:

```
error: cannot declare ‘::main’ to be a template
```

You are writing as if you believe that `Tmp` is called a template. If so, then correct that by looking back at your textbook/tutorial/whatever. `Tmp` *is not a template*. It is a template parameter. In your second code snippet, `add` is a function template, and `Tmp` is still not a template, it's the template parameter of `add`.

You can use template parameters inside the template whose parameters they are. For example, the following is fine:

```
template <class Tmp>
Tmp add(Tmp x, Tmp y)
{
    Tmp total = x + y;
    return total;
}
```

Your problem is just that when you tried this you tried it in `main`, which cannot be a template.